# Which way to distribute iPad app

Tags: ios

We're a small company and have developed an iPad app we would like to give to our customers. I've read through the B2B option but don't like our customers having to register their DUN info with Apple.

Should I just load it in the App store and put in the description that it's a private App? It requires a login so it doesn't matter if other folks download it.

Currently, we're using it in house via the internal tester scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one but Apple can say for certain what Apple will do in any specific case, but your description suggests it will be rejected.

From Apple's App Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

If you don't have a base functionality that applies to the general public, you will, in all likelihood, need to go Enterprise delivery.

Comment: Can you use Enterprise delivery for none employees?

Comment: Honestly, I've assumed there's a way to do it based on past interactions, but I'm not an expert on that part. A quick review hasn't given me any ammo yet to prove/disprove.

Comment: This deconstruction looks very useful in understanding some of the subtleties - http://mobiledan.net/2012/09/08/can-ios-enterprise-apps-be-used-by-customers/ - basically, there are conforming ways to use enterprise for "customers", but this doesn't seem to be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that spells it out.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing publicly might be the best option, but I don't think you would get an approval if you describe it as a private app in your description.

Without knowing too much about your business or the nature of your app, it's hard to suggest, but possibly you could add some public usefulness on the front-end of your app, even if that's business info, contact information, a news feed, etc... with the real intent of the app being tucked behind a login portal. (all total speculation).

Distributing the app outside of the app store has a lot of limitations as well: http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

Answer (score 0):

I would just submit to the app store and see what happens.  Apple may reject it, but that is true in any case.  I have an app of this nature, submitted with a couple of test accounts, no problem getting it approved.  When the app launches, it pops a logon screen, and has a short message about where to get an account (which won't make much sense to people not in the intended audience).